# How to create Step definition from BDD feature file in visual studio using WDIO

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, webdriver-io, wdio-v5

How to create step definition from BDD feature file using WDIO framework

```
Scenario Outline: Verify the weatherForecast Application whether user can able to lunch the application for mentioned city
    When I open the url http://localhost:3000/
    Then I should be able to launch the application with header "Five Day Weather Forecast foreee"
    When I enter the <cityName> for weatherForecast

    Examples:
      | cityName  |
      | aberdeen  |
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which IDE do you use? Which plugins do you have installed for the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the official docs? They have really good boilerplate projects which will help in understanding the base setup.

https://webdriver.io/docs/boilerplate.html

Answer (score 0):

You should find some working examples, nothing else, check this repository:
https://github.com/webdriverio/cucumber-boilerplate